# error in installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello can any one please help me, I am getting this sort of error when I am trying to install rails version of 3.2.0 on my linux(I already have rails version 2.3.5 installed) thanx in advance!

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: run `bundle install` from your application folder. This will install the version of rails which is defined in your gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project directory and install the bundle with following command. 
`bundle install` 
 Then start server.